# Standard order to the results of N Choose K?

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say I have 15 items. They are labeled item-1, item-2, item-3 etc.

Let's say I then get the results of 15-choose-1, 15-choose-2, 15-choose-3, etc.

**Is there a customary way to then order the results of each group?**

That is, for 15-choose-3, we'll have (item-1, item-2, item-3) as one of the results. This would be a logical choice to name as the '1st result of 15-choose-3'.

But then for (item-1, item-2, item-4)....is this the '2nd result of 15-choose-3'?

Or is (item-2, item-3, item-4) considered the '2nd result of 15-choose-3'?

**Is there a standard?**

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is no agreed upon convention.  When I am attacking such a problem, I will intentionally order the elements in ascending order, from left to right, and then have the subsets be in *dictionary* order.  For example, taking $(3)$ elements from $\{12,\cdots,9\}$, the next subset that I would take after $\{1,2,9\}$ would be $\{1,3,4\}.$

Comment: Consider a string of 15 1's and 0's. If there's a 0 in the i'th position then item #i is not in your set, and if it's a 1 then it is. So choices match up with 15 digit binary numbers. I've often see the results presented in the order corresponding to the numbers listed from larger to smaller.

Comment: Lexicographic ordering is the usual, or one of its variants: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order#Finite_subsets

Comment: [Colexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order#Colexicographic_order) may also be preferred based on situation, that is where we organize based on the largest element: (1,2,3),(1,2,4),(1,3,4),(2,3,4),(1,2,5),(1,3,5),(2,3,5),(1,4,5),(2,4,5),(3,4,5),(1,2,6),...   Another order might have been to organize based on the sums of the indices used: (1,2,3),(1,2,4),(1,2,5),(1,3,4),(1,2,6),(1,3,5),(2,3,4),... There are many different options and no single choice is "most correct."  It all depends on what your particular situation is and what is most helpful to your application

Comment: Part of why Colex order is so useful is that the list will start out the same regardless whether you were taking subsets from (1,2,3,...,10) or whether you were taking subsets from (1,2,3,...,1000).

Comment: Very interesting replies, thanks. Also, @JMoravitz, do we have an efficient way to determine the answer to questions like "what is the x-th element within the co-lexicographic ordering of 15-choose-3"? And vice versa? Can we efficiently go from the element, to the number it is within the ordering?

Comment: @Parry:  yes and it has been described here and on the web.  The first ${15 \choose 3}-{14\choose 3}$ triplets have $1$ as the first element.  Then you are looking for the xth element of $14 \choose 2$  If it is greater, see if it has $2$ as a first element.  It makes a nice recursive algorithm

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm having some trouble understanding the definition of colex ordering. How would it start with choosing 4 elements? Thanks

Comment: In (*normal*) lex order, to compare two subsets $A$ and $B$ you write the elements in each set in increasing order.  If the first element in $A$ is less than the first element in $B$ then $A$ appears in lex order before $B$ and vice versa.  Otherwise if the first elements in each were the same then move on to ask about the second elements of each.  Continue moving forward through the elements until finally a comparison does not tie.  Colex order is exactly the same with just one key difference: you start the comparisons with the largest element instead and go through them in reverse.

Comment: @Parry So it starts (1,2,3,4), (1,2,3,5), (1,2,4,5), (1,3,4,5), (2,3,4,5), (1,2,3,6), (1,2,4,6), (1,3,4,6), (2,3,4,6), (1,2,5,6), (1,3,5,6), (2,3,5,6), (1,4,5,6), (2,4,5,6), (3,4,5,6), (1,2,3,7) and so on.  If you compare to my list for length three subsets from earlier, you should recognize for instance that when I was writing those sets who ended with a 6 the first three elements followed the same pattern as before.